# datacolumn datagridview replace specific value

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

i have a datagridview in my C# program.after i bind  it to a datasource , i want to replace some value in a specific column  in automatically generated  rows.for example   i have columns in which have 0 or 1 values , and i want to replace true or false . what should i do ?

Comment: I think this question should be left open because it is a real question. It is not ambiguous, incomplete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) Event.

This event is called when it's time to format a cell.  One of the more useful things you can do in this event is change the content and appearance of a cell based on the cell's value.

You'll want to study the code in the documentation but I have a snippet below that shows a little you can do.  The CellFormatting event below checks if it's formatting a cell in a column called "Column3" and if it is and the cell's value is 0 (as a string) ,it changes the cell's value to "False" and the cell's BackColor to red.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Column3") {
        if (e.Value.ToString() == "0") {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            e.Value = "False";
        }
    }
}
```