# SQL - Insert NULL into DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table where I add `Datetime` into some columns. I use a stored procedure to insert values into the table. In the stored procedure I have variables that accept null for inserting into the table. My problem is when I try to insert a null value into my table column I get 1900-01-01 in the column. What do I do so instead of this default value insert only NULL in the colulmn??

This is my SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Insert
@InserID int,
@InsertDate Datetime = null,
AS
Insert into Tables(InsertID, InsertDate)
Values(@InsertID, @InsertDate)
```

I do this to assign a null value:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime getDate;
//set DateTime null
getDate = SqlDateTime.Null;

if (InsertDate.Text == "")
{
cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = getDate;
}
else
{
cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = InsertDate.Text;
}
```

The value that adds to my table column is not NULL, its 1900-01-01.

What do I do?

Comment: Does the column `InsertDate` have a default specified in the table definition?

Comment: @Brook: That would be a good answer!

Comment: InsertDate can be both null and a valid date.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this pattern and I have no problems with nulls or incompatible text format.

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add["@InsertDate"].Value = textBox1.Text.AsDBDateTime();
// ...
public static class DBValueExtensions {
    public static object AsDBDateTime(this string s) {
        object dateTimeValue;
        var str = s;
        if ( null != str ) { str = str.Trim(); }

        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ) {
            dateTimeValue = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else {
            dateTimeValue = DateTime.Parse(str);
        }

        return dateTimeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can omit optional parameters entirely, instead of setting them to `SqlDateTime.Null`.

Having said that, the code should still work.  How do you read the database?  Some viewers display `1900-01-01` for `null`.  What do you see when you run `select * from Tables` from SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I read all the values that are in the table into a DataGridView using a datasource.

Comment: @Man1: So what do you see if you look at the table in SQL Server Management Studio?  Or in Visial Studio's "server explorer"?

Comment: @Man1: What does `select isnullable from syscolumns where name = 'InsertDate' and id = object_id('Tables')` return?

Comment: @Man1: Ok... What happens when you replace `if (InsertDate.Text == "")` with `if(true)` ?

Comment: @Main1: And what does `select definition from sys.default_constraints dc join sys.columns c on dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id and dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id where c.name = 'InsertDate' and c.object_id = object_id('Tables')` return?

Comment: @Andomar: It doesnt return eny thing :S, what should it return?

Comment: @Andomar: I have removed the if-statement. Instead I have declared a variable as object, then in the if-statement: if that object variable is not null I assign another DATETIME variable the value of the object value, if the object variable is null then I assign it the value of getDate like this: (DateTime)getDate. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Man1: If it doesn't return anything, you have no default constraint on your column.  That means you can probably focus on the C# code.  Have you tried not to add the parameter at all, if you want it to be `null`?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there is an implicit conversion from DBNull to 0 for your date because DateTime is not nullable by default. This would reproduce the behaviour you are seeing.

lol, having just seen the Addomar's answer, if the column in SSMS is not actually null but in fact zero and you cant change the database schema (sometimes this isnt possible) then the approach below will work...

You could try something like [datacolumn datagridview replace specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716984/datacolumn-datagridview-replace-specific-value) to replace the value zero with some different text or a blank string?

But ideally change the column to be nullable with no default and omit the parameter when it should be null.

Comment: I know about the replace specific value. But there got to be a way to not att 1900-01-01 value to my table.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in SSMS

```
declare @InsertDate datetime

set @InsertDate = '   '

select @InsertDate
```

which returns `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

so another possibility is your input is whitespace.  Try using

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InsertDate.Text))
```

instead of

```
if (InsertDate.Text == "")
```