# What should be a default datetime value?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I am inserting Excel Sheet records in my `DataTable` in `c#` and passing this DataTable to an SQL `stored procedure`. In my c# code I have put certain checks for `empty` data cells of Excel sheet to avoid Exceptions. But It seems like I am missing something while giving a `default` value for my SQL `Date` field.

```
string InvoiceDate = (row.Cells[3].Text == "&nbsp;") ? "0/00/0000 00:00:00 AM" : (row.Cells[3].Text);
```

And I get the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store
>   <0/00/0000 00:00:00 AM> in InvoiceDate Column.  Expected type is
>   DateTime.

**Edited -** 
Declaration of SQL field [InvoiceDate]

```
[InvoiceDate] [date] NOT NULL
```

Please don't suggest inserting `null` as I cannot Insert `null` for this column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Insert NULL into DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362446/sql-insert-null-into-datetime)

Comment: Why are you passing string, if your database column is datetime?

Comment: Try using `DateTime.Min` - I think this is 1/Jan/1900

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri When I `debug` my code with Excel sheet containing `5/31/2015` in Date column I get `5/31/2015 12:00:00 AM` in my `InvoiceDate` variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, There is no `00/00/0000` date, not in the real world and not in sql server.

**Second**, why do you even need a default values? just use null instead.

**Third**, use ISO 8601 format for specifying dates in strings (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`)

**Forth**, As [Giorgi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651298/giorgi-nakeuri) rightfully pointed out in his comment, why even use strings for a datetime value? use a variable of type [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime(v=vs.110).aspx) in `c#`. note that it's min value is different then the sql server `DateTime` data type min value.

If your [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) column is not nullable, you can use `1753-01-01` (min value for datetime) or `9999-12-31` (max value for datetime)

One last thing, you might want to consider using either [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) or separate the date and time to different columns (data types [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) and [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx), of course). Why? [read here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime)

Comment: According to the design of the table, I cant insert NULL values in my column.

Comment: I've already included a part for such situation in my answer: **If your datetime column is not nullable, you can use 1753-01-01 (min value for datetime) or 9999-12-31 (max value for datetime)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the current date instead:

```
string InvoiceDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[3].Text) ? DateTime.Now.ToString() : (row.Cells[3].Text);
```

Comment: Please remove `? "0/00/0000 00:00:00 AM"` part from your code ;).